# Iterating throug SVG elements with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

What I'm trying to do is relatively simple but I'm new to JS and D3.js. 
I have created a bunch of rectangles using SVG through D3.js.

I added some code to handle a click event and in there I'd like to iterate through all drawn nodes and do something with them as long as a specific property matches the same property in the one that's been clicked.

Here's the code that draws the rectangles (only one of them here);

```
d3.select("svg")
.append("rect").attr("x", 50)
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("height", 20)
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("title", "catalog")
.style("fill", "#CB4B19")
.on("click", mouseClick)
```

And here's how I'm trying to retrieve the "title" property of each rectangle drawn and compare it to the clicked one (and in this case, just log it in the console). I know this is probably basic but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
function mouseClick(d) {

  var t = d3.select(this).attr("title");     //store the "title" property  of the clicked rectangle

  d3.selectAll("rect").each(function(d, i){  //Select all rectangles drawn
  if(d3.select(this).attr("title") == t){    //for each one, if the "title" property = the one initially chosen
   console.log(t);                          //do something here
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually seems to be working correctly. At least for me it did. One thing I will say is that d3 does mimic jQuery syntax in that it lets you select elements with attributes with the `d3.select('element[attributeName="?"]')` syntax. You can read more about [`selections` here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections).

So for your example, you could do

```
var t = d3.select(this).attr("title"); 

// select all rectangles with the attribute title
d3.selectAll("rect[title='" + t + "']").each(function(d, i){
   console.log(t);                          
});
```

You no longer need the if statement to check because you are only selecting them. I made a simple jsFiddle to show this. I made 3 different types of rectangles with different `title` attributes and when you click on them, it only selects `rect` that have the same `title` attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/znqe8nqr/

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. I actually copied/typed the code right but had a different element there ("svg" instead of "rect") in the code. It does make sense to access the attribute directly, thanks for that.